# Is there any work around to be able to use multiple "correct" metrics for keras learning on TPU?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu, tpu

I made small model using Keras on Google colaboratory.
And I see wrong metrics when I run learning on TPU.

When I run learning on CPU/GPU, of course, m1 and m2 metrics shows correct number. (see below code)

But after I change runtime type to TPU, m1 and m2 is not correct and it looks like average of these values.

```py
def m1(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.constant(10)

def m2(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.constant(20)

model = AnyModel()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=[m1, m2])
model.fit(...)
```

[result of CPU/GPU]

```
[=====>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: xxxxx - m1: 10.0000 - m2: 20.0000
```

[result of TPU]

```
[=====>....] - ETA: 0s - loss: xxxxx - m1: 14.9989 - m2: 15.0000
```

It is obvious that the result of CPU/GPU is correct.
Why is this happened?
Is there any workaround?

- If I use only one metrics (like [m1]), the value is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, it works!

Multiple metrics can be used correctly with Tensorflow version 1.14.0-rc1.
I guess it was a bug of tf or keras, but now it has been solved.

(Notice: On ver.1.14.0-rc1, `fit_generator` cannot be used! But it should be solved soon.)

If you use tensorflow 1.13 or less for some reason, mind this bug and you can use just one metric.